# How to set progress bar 0 in android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

When user cancel a download running, progress bar must go to first. for this purpose I set progress (0) but progress bar don't go to first but remains in that same situation:

```
progressBar.setProgress(0);
```

What should I do?

Comment: add some more code, previous codes of progress bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood that it works properly. In fact, after running this method, I should stop the loop that contains update the progress bar

Answer (score 3):

Progress bar has two modes:

1.Indeterminate mode

```
<ProgressBar
              android:id="@+id/indeterminateBar"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

2.Determinate mode

```
<ProgressBar
      android:id="@+id/determinateBar"
      style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal" //this line is import!
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:progress="25"/> //initial progress bar position(25%), also could be set via java codes.
```

Notice: `setProgress` method is **invalid** for indeterminate mode.